How to produce a Sine squared wave - Frequency Modulation
I want to make use of the trigonometrical identity \$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1\$.
I have the sine wave (and have the cos too, but we can ignore that because it will be the same process) and want to get sine squared from it.  One possibility would have been to use an XR2206 or XR2209 and use the chip's modulation function with the same sine function on both terminals.  The way I thought of doing it was simply to vary the gain on a CE stage sinusoidally at the same frequency; effectively varying what would be the quiescent current — and I'd do probably do that by applying the signal to the transistor that otherwise would have been part of the Constant Current Sink.
But before setting off on this route, it occurred to me that there must be a huge body of knowledge on how to do this, probably under the heading of Frequency Modulation, and that it would doubtless cover all the main pitfalls, given there's about a century of Radio Frequency work (and that's where the best electronics engineers are).
I'm also a little concerned about some of those double angle trig identities showing up.  I don't mind if it all shows up as twice the frequency — in fact, that would be rather nice — but I want to avoid 2f showing up if the output is generally the fundamental.  I.e.  I don't want it degrading into 2f if, say, the two terms of the equation aren't of identical amplitude.  OTOH, a small amount of ripple on the output (after summation) is of little consequence.
So, where would people suggest I look for a good background on the topic, and how would you implement this?
Later edit:  The pink is the waveform I want to synthesise.  The remainder of the blue waveform (the 4 quadrant square, I presume, being 2f) is underneath the pink.


Mathematically, it appears the easiest approach is to use an analog multiplier such as AD633 and apply sine(x) to both inputs.  Frequency doubling is unavoidable; the AD633 datasheet shows how to avoid the DC offset produced by simple multiplication.

It rather depends on why you're doing this, to give some context to any answers. Self education, hobby project, fixed or variable input frequency, what's available in the rest of the system, are you trying to make a commercial product?

You can also use an 'analog multiplier IC' and feed your sinewave to both inputs to get sin^2 output. I think RF peoples use components called 'mixers' for multiplying signals at higher frequencies

What sort of frequency are you trying to achieve, and what sort of accuracy?

@user131342  I take it you mean it's all going to be 2f.  That's what I get on LTspice doing it just mathematically. I'm having some conceptual difficulty in seeing why this happens.  This should be mapping out a circle and is just a bit of Pythagoras.   Maybe I need some sort of Mag or ABS function (an area I know LTspice is very ropey).  Point by point I want an amplitude of 0.707 to become 0.5 and 0.5 to become 0.25 etc..  A sine at 2f doesn't doesn't give me that unity output when added to a matching cosine.  I'm aware I may need to split this into pos and neg going sections.

@jonathanjo In the 10s to early 100s c/s.  I'm not worried about distortion as it will be bandpass filtered, or DC offset, provided it's not eating into my headroom, as it'll be AC coupled into an amp that's either bridged or dual railed.  I have to be a little bit circumspect about filtering though, as I don't at the moment know what frequency components are in a sin^2 function.  Frequency drift could be a problem but that probably applies to whatever oscillator is feeding it.  Amplitude can be trimmed.

@Neil_UK  It's just an idea for how to improve something which I'm going to experiment with at home.  The frequency would be largely fixed but could be variable within a small range.  What stops it being variable is the filtering which would otherwise have to track the input frequency and mean the addition of considerable complexity.   At the moment all I need to do is produce the sine squared function and there's no restriction at all on how it's done, though I shan't be doing anything at all pricey.

If you're not worried about distortion, and will filter it, then full wave rectification is all you need. That's how RF/microwave doublers work.

@Neil_UK  Haha!  Other way round.  I'm after a sine squared function, not just a frequency doubler.  From the LTspice screen grab I've added to the question, you can see there's an awful lot of 2f in it (indeed it largely looks like a 2f that has been reflected in its lower bound).   But what you've just said has sparked some possible ideas that might be the way simplest way to create it, without doing the multiplication.  The bias can be varied wherever we want (and to get over diode drops) and some combination of rectification, inversion and summing might give us a route to the waveform.

From your later edit: "The pink is the waveform I want to synthesise." The pink waveform is not the square of the green waveform. It is like $ sin(x) |sin(x)| $. Using the absolute value for one of the terms preserves the sign of the waveform.

@Transistor  Yes, I'm aware of that and also included the green waveform multiplied by itself, but that's basically 2f with some <1mV errors at the top of the cycle (not sure the source of those).  Another sine wave doesn't get me ahead in implementing the identity at the top of the question.
I'm not sure we should be taking into account the signs of the different quadrants, or even the phase, as we're kind of at one point, with the waveform passing by and only seeing the amplitudes. But, as I said in one of my replies above, I'm struggling with this conceptually.

@Transistor  After doing a bit more thinking and some simulation, it turns out both terms need to be Abs()ed.  So the pink waveform was NOT the target waveform - as I guess you suspected.  It actually looks not much different from a sine wave and doesn't appear to have that 2f component - though I bet it does.  I've done the cosine version too and added them together, and they do give a perfect straight line.  So that's the theoretical part shown to be good.  Now for the implementation ...

I'm finding it very difficult to figure out what you are asking! A square of a sine will always contain a 2f component as indicated from trigonometry: $ sin^2(\theta) = \frac 1 2 (1 - cos(2\theta))$.

I'm not going to repeat the maths; refer to the AD633 datasheet for the trig functions. You will get the sine squared output from a sine input. If you want the cosine squared function in addition then you need a separate (but identical) circuit.
